# How to delete message if it's not starting with specified word. Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to know how to make function that deletes message if it's not starting with specified "word" not when message includes the word specified but when it's starting with it (everything on specified channel with channel id), it's very important for me and I can't find any solution online. I've tried nothing because I don't know how to make it.

Comment: Keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Please try to create your code by yourself before posting for debug support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome, you can listen to the "message" event and check if the message starts with the string of your need. Example for you here:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

// Making our Discord Client
const client = new Discord.Client();

// Listens for the new message event
client.on("message", (message) => {
    // String of your need
    const str = "word";

    // Checking if string starts with your string of preference
    if (message.content.startsWith(str)) {
        // Deleting the message
        message.delete();
    }
});
```

I hope this helped you, you can read more about the event listeners [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message).

Answer (score 2):

#### String#startsWith()

The above method returns a boolean of whether a certain string starts with a certain value. For example:

```js
const str = 'Hello world!'

console.log(str.startsWith('Hello')) // Output: 'true'
console.log(str.startsWith('world')) // Output: 'false'

/* Using in an if statement */
if (str.startsWith('Hello')) {
  // This will execute the code since the value returns true
}
```

You can now use the above method in order to delete messages that start with the specified word of your choosing.

Comment: yea but i mean discord bot.

Comment: I'm not going to give you the code on how to use this method through a discord bot. Please learn how to implement this by yourself.

Comment: can u help me a bit with code for message?

Comment: @LixerMan [here](https://discordjs.guide/#before-you-begin) is a guide on how to create discord bots with `discord.js`